# Unable to login as root in mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bitnami, mysql-slow-query-log

I've been trying out all solutions mentioned in google for this problem to no avail. This website is built using bitnami wordpress stack in AWS. All I want to do is to log slow query. I only have wp-config user credentials to login in to mysql. But with this access I cannot run `SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';`
as it requires super user privilege.

To my understanding, unless I login as root user and assign the privilege to this user or run the command as root user itself no other workaround to get this sorted.

Problem is, no password for root. Maybe it's configured without password when it was first installed (mysql).

I checked this file for password but found none.

```
/opt/bitnami/mysql/my.cnf
```

I can't view the mysql log too (permission denied)
/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log

I dont find the password in aws->instance settings -> get system log

I tried resetting password as mentioned here. https://community.bitnami.com/t/unable-to-reset-mysql-root-password/44360/3
mysql stops but stuck at starting in safe mode forever usin below commands:

```
$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop mysql
$ sudo /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

How do I enable the slow query log now or get root password or reset it?

Comment: Did you set `log_output`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bitnami Engineer here,

The root's password of the database is the same one the instance configures for WordPress during the boot process. That means that if you have not changed the WordPress' admin password, both passwords are the same now.

You can open the bitnami_credentials file in the home folder of the bitnami user to obtain the password the instance used during the configuration process.

```
cat /home/bitnami/bitnami_credentials
```

After that, just run the mysql command to access the database

```
mysql -u root -p
```